# Elastic Search must not queries are slow

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have a test index of 50K documents.
I'm firing 500 (same) queries against it, which have a clause that a field (that is an array of values) "must not" be of "some value".
Out of these 500 queries several fail/time out. (Sometimes it's 5, sometimes it's 9, sometimes it's 18 queries...) Is there a way to make the "must not" queries faster? In production the index is going to be several million docs, and the majority of queries are going to have "must not" clauses.

Mapping is as follows:

```
{  
"jobs_en":{  
"mappings":{  
  "index":{  
    "_all":{  
      "enabled":false
    },
    "properties":{  
      "GUID":{  
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      },
      "channel":{  
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      },
      "country":{  
        "type":"string",
        "analyzer":"standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

The query is as follows:

```
{ 
"bool" : {
"must" : [ {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "bool" : { }
    },
    "must_not" : {
      "term" : {
        "channel" : "Email"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "match" : {
        "country" : {
          "query" : "US",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ]
  }
}"
```

Comment: You sure it's only happening with must_not queries?

Comment: please share your mapppings and query examples, that fails

Comment: I have noticed some performance problems with must_not as well. If your data set allows that (if you have a small set of known values for channel), you can replace it with `must` `terms`.

Answer (score 2):

We have a large database in ES, I don't think it is as large as yours.  Several things help me:
1. Use Must if you can.
2. Use Must Not WITH Must.
3. If you are able to: use Source.

```
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        {"term": {
            "createUser": {
              "value": "processor.imsignal"
            }
          }
        },
        {"terms" : {
          "imcampaignid"  : [70191,66983,70188,70235,70190]
        }     
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {"term": {
            "source": {
              "value": "EMAIL"
            }
          }
        },
        {"terms" : {
          "category"  : ["campaign_email","unsubscribe","from_email"]
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    "_source": ["category","source","accountPlatformID"]
```

By specifying a must first, it speeds up the query.  By specifying must_not it can reduce the number of returned records which can be a real hit.  Finally, reducing what is returned on those records can really be helpful.

Since there was no other answer, I figured I'd help with what I knew.  Believe it or not, this query with the must not outperforms the identical query with only the musts for my purposes by tens of seconds.  Telling something what it should be is essential, then filter with what it is not.